# Cross-browser @media query to detect retina display?

Tags: html, css, retina-display

So far I was only able to find following media query:

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

However it seems it only supports webkit browsers, is there a similar query for (at least)
-moz- and -ms- (-o-) browsers?

Comment: what you are trying to do is specifically for apple's retina branding, which means that only a webkit and a non-prefixed version exist, feel free to use them, but they mainly apply to apple's devices as a way to specify an apple high-resolution devices apart from all other devices with similar specifications.

Comment: let me know if you need any help with the media queries, they can be tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do instead of detecting device-pixel-ratio or min-resolution, you can detect the device width which is the resolution of the screen size instead of the viewport width which is the resolution of the browser size. This first of all gives you a correct media query when attempting to target specific devices, and to detect "retina" device you will need to use:

```
@media screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
/* code goes here */
}
```

This sets up the media query to identify devices that are scaled like retina displays on iDevices and helps target them only to avoid other devices receiving these css styles.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Isn't this against all sanity and reasoning behind CSS? To write hacks that **you** think only targets devices from a certain vendor? This is non-portable and ugly, and there is still no such thing as retina.

Comment: @gustafr, what Ilya Knaup is trying to do is target a retina device, (apple's branding of high-resolution devices) specifically, which is actually a good idea because the styles you apply to them should very well be different than the ones you apply to my BlackBerry PlayBook. While both do have the same resolution, one scales it's content and should use higher-quality images to take advantage of the hardware it has, which is not against css, this isn't a hack. It is a method of enhancing the user experience on devices that can handle it and saving bandwidth on devices that dont need good image

Comment: I'm on a flatrate ~6mbit/s prescription with my phone and tablet with high resolutions. Who are you to say I "don't need" a high resolution image? Also, your solution is for **a certain resolution** and has nothing to do with generic "retina" resolutions.

Comment: You change the device width and height parameters as necessary for your devices...or if you just want to say that all images should be 2x resolution, you don't need them and can just use the webkit and non-prefixed device pixel ratios to tell those devices to load the 2x versions and leave everything else the same.

Comment: And then we'll have 3x and 1.3x and 1.8x and 2.4x, and 40 different resolutions, and ... And, you *won't care* about supporting them all but only Apple's and a few others (in best case), and instead of a generic solution that works (like all web pages that aren't trying to be smart), your web page will work for some devices and be crappy for others.  Consider if this is a risk you're willing to take.

Comment: If you are looking for complete interoperability, this is what is necessary right now.

Answer (score -4):

There is no such thing as a *retina display*. I have a MacBookPro with what Apple labels as "retina" (so I understand what it is you think you mean), but the word is completely made-up and really means nothing.

So, you won't be able to detect it as much as you won't be able to detect a "high performing gaming computer", which is as strictly defined.

Comment: A bit pedantic, but he's right. What you're really detecting is resolution, or pixel density. Retina screens have a wide variety of pixel densities.